# auto, error: map iterator has no member named ‘first`

Tags: c++, iterator

```
map<string, int> M;
for (auto E: M) 
{ 
    cout << E.first << ": " << E.second << endl; 
    F << E.first << ": " << E.second << endl; 
};
```

I am learning c++ and I am confused with auto. I am trying to convert the above code into the following code( the above code with auto works correctly)

```
map<string, int> M;
for (map<string, int> :: iterator p = begin(M); p != end(M); p ++ )
{
    cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << endl;
    F << p.first << ": " << p.second << endl;
}
```

I got the following error:

```
 error: ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>::iterator’ has no member named ‘first’
     cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << endl;
 error: ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>::iterator’ has no member named ‘second’
     cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << endl;
 error: ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>::iterator’ has no member named ‘first’
     F << p.first << ": " << p.second << endl;
 error: ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>::iterator’ has no member named ‘second’
     F << p.first << ": " << p.second << endl;
```

Why it does not work?

Comment: Not related to your question, but consider using `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`if you do not intend to change the mapped values

Comment: _"I am trying to convert the above code into the following code( the above code with auto works correctly)"_ The above code is superior in almost every way (a reference wouldn't hurt) so why are you trying to convert it? For what purpose? Furthermore, switching from ranged-for doesn't mean you can't use `auto`; the two features are orthogonal.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: If you are confused by auto just switch it to normal declaration, for this case `std::pair<const std::string, int>&`. And start using foreach as it was like leaving the cave for c++. You can not imagine how more readable some code become after this one little construct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterators are like pointers and must be dereferenced for use:

```
cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << endl;
```

The ranged-for loop (the example with `auto`) did this for you.

Comment: I would like to suggest removing the last line to your response as it does not contribute to the solution of the user's problem and comes off as if the asker should have known the answer to his problem prior to asking it... I'm aware this is a nearly 5 year old question now, but SO could use less of this.